# LISP programming

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

```lisp
(defun bubbleUp (n)
  (cond
    ((null n) nil)
    ((null (cdr n)) n)
    ((> (car n) (car (cdr n)))
     (append (list (car (cdr n)))
             (bubbleUp (cons (car n) (cdr (cdr n))))))
    (t (append (list (car n)) (bubbleUp (cdr n))))))
```

I wanted to write a sort function that uses this bubbleUp function.

A call to sort will output the following:

```lisp
> (sort ‘(5 4 3 2 1)) > (1 2 3 4 5)

> (sort ‘(6 4 3 9 8))

> (3 4 6 8 9)
```

But Ijust want to use LISP functions: defun, cond, car, cdr, list, cons, append, >, <, >=, <=, = and null. I dn't want to use (setq and set)

Comment: You should start by reading the LISP documentation for `sort`, `defun`, `cond`, `car`, `cdr`, `list`, etc. There's lots of documentation online and examples. Then make an attempt and ask a specific question where you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question you have to apply `bubble-up` (which would a more lispy way to name the function) again until `(apply #'< sorted-list)` is true, where `sorted-list` is the result of `bubble-up`.

Of course, this is just a *homework solution* and should not be used if performance could be an issue. Furthermore you should think about if it is clever to get your homework done on SO ;-)

I guess, the most simple pattern would look like this (taking your function bubble-up as given):

```
(defun bubble-sort (list)
  (cond ((apply #'< list) list)
        (t (bubble-sort (bubble-up list)))))

CL-USER> (bubble-sort '(6 4 3 9 8 10 1 12))
==> (1 3 4 6 8 9 10 12)
```

But be warned, I am not a very experienced Lisp programmer and this code is extra-ordinary inefficient. If you really want to sort a list you should use sort and read more about tail-call-optimization and iteration. The info tab has further resources.

Comment: Can you please guide me. I am new in LISP programming. I know how to do this in C but I don't know how to do in LISP. I am stuck. I will be really thankful if you help me out.